# Is there automated upvoter in CS?

Tags: support, vote-count

Sometimes I see question has 0 view and 1 upvote, or 1 view and two upvotes! how it is possible? Funny thing is that it happens numerous times. (first time I saw I thought that it's my mistake but I saw this situation again and again).

Comment: That might just be a synchronisation problem. Votes and rep are updated in real time these days, view are probably not.

Comment: @Raphael, good guess :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The view count is cached, so you're seeing the view count from a few minutes ago. They're heavily cached because views happen often, they're handled by several different servers, and the exact number is not very important information. Votes, on the other hand, update in real time (even after you have the page open, if your browser is modern enough). If someone has the site's main page open in a browser tab, they'll get a notification (in mine, the tab title flashes when a question comes in), so the first readers can zero in very quickly.

See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80615/view-count-out-of-date-on-a-stack-overflow-question) on the main meta site for more technical details. On a slow-paced site (i.e. not Stack Overflow), view counts can lag more than 5 minutes behind.

Comment: Thanks, nice reference.